# Saving a file asynchronously in ASP.NET Core causing exceptions with DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I have an application that saves document information for customers. I am trying to add functionality to allow users to upload PDFs and have them saved to disk. I am using the recommended code found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads) and [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/288/uploading-files-with-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc).

When the code works, everything looks good -- the document entity is saved to the database and the uploaded file is saved to disk. However, I am getting sporadic exceptions thrown -- things like `System.ObjectDisposedException ("Cannot access a disposed object")`, sometimes a DbUpdate exception saying a reference is null, etc... I can reproduce the issue, but not 100% every time and not with the same exception every time.

I suspect this is somehow being caused by using `CopyToAsync` when saving the file. I am not very experienced with async code and I may be doing something obviously wrong. If I change the method to use the synchronous `CopyTo` instead, it seems to fix the problem. I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

I am injecting my repo and DbContext using AutoFac. Here is the code for the service method which is called by the controller:

```
public async Task<int> SaveDocument(DocumentDetailDto dto, string user, string webRoot)
{
     documentToSave = new Document();

     // Code not shown that maps dto to new document and adds it to context

     if (dto.FileUpload != null && dto.FileUpload.Length > 0)
     {
          var fileName = $"{dto.CustomerId}-{dto.DocumentTypeId}-{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.pdf";

          var filePath = Path.Combine(webRoot, "uploads");

          using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), FileMode.Create))
          {
               await dto.FileUpload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
          }
     }

     _repo.Save(user);

     return documentToSave.Id;
}
```

Do you see anything obviously wrong with this setup? Is there anything special I need to do when using async with a FileStream right before calling save on the context? I'm still trying to debug the errors, but it almost seems like the issue is some kind of conflict between the open FileStream and the DbContext trying to write to the database. Any ideas to try are most welcome!

Edited to add some additional code:

Here is how I am registering the DbContext in Startup.cs:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc();

     // Add DbContext
     var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

     services.AddDbContext<DocContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("InfrastructureLayer")));

      // Add repository
      services.AddScoped<IRepository, EntityFrameworkRepository<DocContext>>();

      services.AddTransient<IResolveUserService, ResolveUserService>();

      // Autofac setup
      var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
      containerBuilder.RegisterModule<ServiceLayer.AutofacModule>();
      containerBuilder.Populate(services);
      var container = containerBuilder.Build();
      return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
 }
```

Here is the `Save` method in the repo:

```
public virtual void Save(string user = "")
{
     var modifiedEntries = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>()
          .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
          .Select(x => x.Entity)
          .ToList();

     foreach (var entity in modifiedEntries)
     {
          entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
          entity.ModifiedBy = user;
     }

     var newEntries = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>()
          .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
          .Select(x => x.Entity)
          .ToList();

     foreach (var entity in newEntries)
     {
          entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
          entity.CreatedBy = user;
     }

     Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And here is how the `SaveDocument` method is called from the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Save(DocumentDetailDto dto, [FromServices]IResolveUserService userService, [FromServices]IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
     _service.SaveDocument(dto, userService.GetUser(), environment.WebRootPath);

     return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Customers", new { id = dto.CustomerId });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing your other DB related code it's hard to tell. Likely you are applying `using(...)` on a `DbContext` somewhere or you registered your `DbContext` as Singleton

Comment: It might be what Tseng said. Also can you show how you're calling the `SaveDocument()` method? If the request finishes before you reach `_repo.Save(user)` your `DbContext` will get out of it's lifetime and be disposed. Make sure that's not happening.

Comment: @Tseng - thanks, I added some more code, maybe that helps a diagnosis...could using "AddScoped" when registering the repo cause this?

Comment: @ErikBožič I added some more code, let me know if that helps...I will take a closer look at how my services are registered and try and test a bit tonight

Comment: @Jim: Do you perform seeding inside `Configure` method?

Comment: `SaveDocument` is async but you don't await it in your Save() method.

Comment: @Jim it is as I guessed. Check Dimitrys anwser below for the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should await for `_service.SaveDocument` to complete. Currently you start it and does not wait its results. Instead you send successful response to user, request is processed, used resources may be disposed at any moment.

Change your controller action to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(...
{
     await _service.SaveDocument(...

     return RedirectToAction(...
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I wasn't thinking that I needed to trace back to the initial call of SaveDocument -- thank you for the help, I'll get the hang of this async stuff eventually!